# Version Space for Linear Classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm looking for a way to characterize the informativeness of an active learner's labeled data (search/sampling). One idea is to get a measure of how much of the hypothesis space their data has ruled out. Seems like a version space, but most of the examples I'm finding are for rectangular boundaries/categories. In my task there there is a single linear boundary (I'm an experimental psychologist).

I've found an example where the "area" of candidate hypotheses is called the region of disagreement (Figure 7 - right panel; http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/papers/twoface.pdf).

So my questions-
1. Does this seem reasonable or are there better ways to think a version space for linear boundaries?
2. Any ideas about packages/methods to calculate something like this?

Any help would be great!